# Resolution of device running under Windows RT 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-rt

in my application working under windows RT 8.1 I need to determine screen resolution of the current device.

First I need a scale factor:

```
dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => {scaleFactor = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().RawPixelsPerViewPixel; }).AsTask().Wait();
```

It works fine.

Now I need the width and height:

```
Window.Current.Bounds.Width * scaleFactor
```

The problem is that in my method `Window.Current` is null.

Question: what is the proper way of determining screen resolution of device running on windows RT 8.1?

Comment: What scope is your method in?

Comment: It is a public getter method of a public class

Comment: Is that class a `Page`?

Comment: No, this is just a class which does not inherit or implement anything.